# How to select and compare id's of a json file and write new json files for each result in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, select, compare

I have a JSON file with two kinds of arrays, namely Persons and Cars.
Each person has an ID and with each person they have a car or multiple cars. Each kind of car has also an ID.
First I want to create a new directory. In that directory, I want to create new JSON files named (first_name and last_name). In that file I want to select the person and the car with the same id and store them in the JSON file. I don't want to use loops. I can create the directory but the JSON files are not being created.

An example of how json file looks like:

#### JSON file:

```
{
  "persons": [{
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Jos",
    "last_name": "Vertommen",
    "birth_day": "1974-03-23",
    "gender": "M",
    "married": true,
    "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/200x80.png?text=Jos",
    "yearsService": 12
  }],
  "cars": [{
    "id": 1,
    "license": "1-AAA-123",
    "brand": "Opel",
    "model": "Zafira",
    "personId": 1
  }]
```

#### node.js file

```js
'use strict';
let fs = require("fs");
let jsondata = require("../persons.json");
fs.mkdtemp("cars", (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  fs.readFile('../persons.json', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
    let persons = jsondata.persons;
    let cars = jsondata.cars;

    if (persons.id === cars.id) {
      jsondata = JSON.stringify(data)
      let naam = (persons["first_name"] + "_" + persons["last_name"]).toString();
      fs.writeFile(`cars/${naam}.json`, jsondata, () => {})
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: `persons` is an array, so it doesn’t have an id property. You’re going to have to loop or limit yourself to a single element of the array. You could use `map` or something like that but that’s looping.

Answer (score 0):

I idk your file system and your code..

I've just created following example on [github](https://github.com/halilcakar/from-json-to-file/blob/master/index.js)

in the same directory with code i added a `persons.json` file which like following.

```
{
  "persons": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "Jos",
      "last_name": "Vertommen",
      "birth_day": "1974-03-23",
      "gender": "M",
      "married": true,
      "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/200x80.png?text=Jos",
      "yearsService": 12
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "first_name": "Halil",
      "last_name": "Cakar",
      "birth_day": "1992-09-02",
      "gender": "M",
      "married": false,
      "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/200x80.png?text=Halil",
      "yearsService": 12
    }
  ],
  "cars": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "license": "1-AAA-123",
      "brand": "Opel",
      "model": "Zafira",
      "personId": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "license": "1-AAA-123",
      "brand": "Opel",
      "model": "Zafira",
      "personId": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "license": "1-AAA-123",
      "brand": "Opel",
      "model": "Zafira",
      "personId": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

```js
"use strict";
let fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile("./persons.json", "utf-8", (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  let persons = data.persons;
  let cars = data.cars;
  // for every person in this persons array
  for (let i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
    // we are getting person
    let person = persons[i];
    // filtering every car he have!
    let personCars = cars.filter((ch) => ch.personId === person.id);
    // create file name
    let filename = `${person.first_name.toLowerCase()}_${person.last_name.toLowerCase()}.json`;
    // i'm just gonna assume that u want to create your files stringified again so
    // create person's json data
    let data = JSON.stringify({ person, cars: personCars });
    // so here we are assuming again that u have a cars/ directory in the same path
    fs.writeFile(`./cars/${filename}`, data, () => {
      // i'm not sure what to use for this maybe consoling every person's file created!
      console.log(person.first_name, " file created!");
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Halil, thank you but is there a possibility without using a for-loop?

Comment: Hmm one way or another if there is more then one person you kinda have to use. What you can do maybe create a function that consumes this like calling it by it self.